# Querying Map Key, values with Morphia

Tags: java, maps, morphia, querying

I have my mongoDB structure like this.

```
{
id : id,
userid : userid,
map :{
      key1 : [value1, value2,value3],
      key2 : [value1, value2,value3],
      key3 : [value1, value2,value3],
      .......
      }

}
```

I like to query the id if the key2 and value3 matches with my argument. I am little clueless about how to do this. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB it must be like:

```
{
   "map.key2 : "value1",
    "map.key3" : "value1",
}
```

In morphia you can also use dot-notations:

```
ds.createQuery<YouEntity>(YouEntity.class).filter("map.key2", "value1")
```

[From](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/morphia/STfIoBSvt9I)